# refrigerator stops working

Tags: refrigerator, appliances

I have a refrigerator in a rental that stopped working. (Kenmore Coldspot model# 106.74264400)  It is less than 5 years old.

On initial inspection it was not cooling, the thermostat was set to five, and the interior light was working; nothing seemed amiss.  I cleaned the coils although they were not terribly dirty.  I turned the temp knob to zero and when I reset it to 5 it went back to cooling normally.

Since then it occasionally will stop working.  If the temp is turned to off and then reset to five, it will return to cooling, sometimes for several weeks.

What could be causing this?

Comment: By not working you mean it stops cooling permanently?  Since it starts back up when you adjust the thermostat, I'd suspect that thing...

Answer (score 1):

One common cause (since you don't give much detail on how, exactly, it stops working) would be an unreliable or broken defrost circuit, and ice building up in air passages, blocking fans, and thus causing the fridge to not cool because cold air can't get from the coils to the fridge.

Another, or possibly related cause would be slightly low refrigerant (a leak that has not progressed to the point of completely not working) making the coils too cold, causing faster than usual ice build up, which the defrost is not compensating for.

Comment: A failing defrost timer is a common one for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the  possibilites.